# Quartz SimpleTrigger scheduled job for specific time, but never runs the job

Tags: java, spring, triggers, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I created a SimpleTrigger in quartz that schedules itself one hour before a certain appointment so that it will send a text to those that it need to. After creating the trigger, I am receiving the log that tells me what time it is scheduled and its doing that without errors. So I'm assuming it is indeed scheduling the job correctly. When the time stated previously comes around it never fires. I get nothing in the logs at all. If it had even entered the class it would have logged something, but nothing past the time it is scheduled is logged.

There is no stack trace or any obvious difference between this job and my other jobs other than the trigger is created dynamically by way of the appointment time. And an object is getting passed to this job.

Here is the Trigger:

```
public static void scheduleTextJob(Appointment appointment ){
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DailyTriggerController.class);

    JobDetail volunteerTextReminder = (JobDetail) newJob(VolunteerTextReminder.class).withIdentity(appointment.getId()).build();

    try{

        SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(appointment.getStartTime());
        Date scheduledTime;
        if(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < 9 || (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == 9 && cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) < 30)){
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        }
        else{
            cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);
        }

        scheduledTime = cal.getTime();

        SimpleTrigger uniqueTrigger = (SimpleTrigger) newTrigger()
                .withIdentity(appointment.getId(), "TextGroup")
                .startAt(scheduledTime)
                .forJob(volunteerTextReminder)
                .build();

        volunteerTextReminder.getJobDataMap().put("appointmentId", appointment.getId());

        Date ft = sched.scheduleJob(volunteerTextReminder, uniqueTrigger);

        log.info(volunteerTextReminder.getKey() + " will run at: " + ft);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the job that it should be running:

```
public class VolunteerTextReminder implements Job {

private @Autowired
HttpServletRequest request;

private static Logger _log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VolunteerTextReminder.class);

private static final String APPLICATION_CONTEXT_KEY = "applicationContext";
/**
 * Quartz requires a public empty constructor so that the
 * scheduler can instantiate the class whenever it needs.
 */
public VolunteerTextReminder() {
}

public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
        throws JobExecutionException {

    SchedulerContext schedulerContext = null;

    AppointmentDAO adao = null;

    VolunteerDAO vdao = null;

    ApplicationContext appContext = getApplicationContext(context);
    if (appContext != null) {
        adao = (AppointmentDAO) appContext.getBean("AppointmentDAO");
        vdao = (VolunteerDAO) appContext.getBean("VolunteerDAO");

        _log.info("appContext created adao");
    }
    else {
        _log.info("web context DID NOT create adao");
    }

    // This job simply prints out its job name and the
    // date and time that it is running
    JobKey jobKey = context.getJobDetail().getKey();
    _log.info("VolunteerTextReminder says: " + jobKey + " executing at " + new Date());

    try {

        JobDataMap data = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
        String id = data.getString("appointmentId");

        assert adao != null;
        List<Person> people = adao.readPersonsByAppointmentId(id);

        List<Person> volunteers = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Person person: people){
            if(person.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("volunteer")){
                volunteers.add(person);
            }
        }

        for(Person volunteer: volunteers){
            Volunteer volunteerToEmail = vdao.getVolunteerToEmailById(volunteer.getLdsAccountId());
            if(volunteerToEmail != null) {
                Appointment appointment = (Appointment) adao.readAppointmentById(id);
                if(!appointment.getCancelled()){
                    createAndSendText(volunteerToEmail, appointment);
                }
            }
        }


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking in Quartz's database tables, and comparing the entry for this job with others?

Comment: Do you keep a reference to the Scheduler somewhere? Otherwise that's going to be garbage collected together with your job.

Comment: We dont have our jobs being saved to a database at this point so, to my knowledge we have nothing to go off of.